# Client socket will not receive data from server

Tags: java, sockets, printwriter, datainputstream, inputstreamreader

My issue is that in my client, `dis.read()` is returning `-1` causing it to never actually receive the file. The only thing that I can think of is that because I use a `PrintWriter` and a `BufferedReader` before this section, the `dis.read()` thinks that all data has been received already.

**Client Code:**

```
public static void receiveFile(String serverAddress, int port, String fileName, String fileOut) throws IOException {
    Socket client = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
    client.setSoTimeout(5000);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

    try {
        out.println("101|" + fileName + "\n");

        if (input.readLine().equals("201")) {
            int br;
            byte[] data = new byte[4096];

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);

            while ((br = dis.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1){
                fos.write(data, 0, br);
            }

            fos.close();
            dis.close();
        }
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
        ste.printStackTrace();
        client.close();
    }
}
```

**Server Code:**

```
private void sendFile(String filename, Socket client) throws IOException {
    int br;
    byte[] data = new byte[4096];
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

    out.println("201\n");

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(MeshFS.properties.getProperty("repository") + filename);

    while ((br = fis.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        dos.write(data, 0, br);
        dos.flush();
    }

    fis.close();
    dos.close();
}

private String receiveRequest(Socket client) {
    String requestPart;
    String requestFull = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

        while (((requestPart = input.readLine()) != null) && (requestFull.length() < 2048)) {
            if (requestPart.equals("")) break;
            requestFull = requestFull + requestPart;
        }

        return requestFull;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return requestFull;
    }
}

private void processRequest(String request, Socket out) {

    if (request != null) {
        try {
            String[] requestParts = request.split("\\|");
            if (requestParts[0].equals("101")) {            //101:Get file
                sendFile(requestParts[1], out);

            } else {
                badRequest(out, request);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            badRequest(out, request);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                server.setSoTimeout(1000);
                Socket client = server.accept();
                client.setSoTimeout(timeout);
                processRequest(receiveRequest(client), client);
                client.close();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Socket closed");
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing or forgetting to include? Am I not flushing something or not clearing something?

Comment: could you provide more code? i would like to see the part where you accept the connection with the serversocket

Comment: I updated my code to include pretty much everything, take a look please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I guess I have found the mistake. I made some experiments and found out that `InputStream`'s behave weird if multiple objects try to read from them. In your case, its very likely the `BufferedReader` and the `DataInputStream` in your client's `receiveFile` method causing the problem by trying to read from the same `inputStream`. I suggest using the `DataInputStream` to also read the first line so you don't have to create a `BufferedReader`. Even though the `DataInputStream.readLine()` method is deprecated, it should still do well in your case.

I edited the clients `receiveFile` method to use the `DataInputStream` to read the first line. Hope it works!

```
public static void receiveFile(String serverAddress, int port, String fileName, String fileOut) throws IOException {
    Socket client = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
    client.setSoTimeout(5000);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

    try {
        out.println("101|" + fileName + "\n");

        if (dis.readLine().equals("201")) {
            int br;
            byte[] data = new byte[4096];

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);

            while ((br = dis.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1){
                fos.write(data, 0, br);
            }

            fos.close();
            dis.close();
        }
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
        ste.printStackTrace();
        client.close();
    }
}
```